# The solvability of a subgroup in $S_{11}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

Is the subgroup in $S_{11}$ generated by cycles $(1,  2, 3, 4, 5)$ and $(1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)$ solvable?

The cycles generating our subgroup have lengths $5$ and $7$, if multiplied, we get a cycle of length $11$, I believe that if we continue multiplying, we can come to the conclusion that these cycles generate $A_{11}$, but it seems that if this is true, it can be done in a more elegant way

Comment: This subgroup is indeed $A_{11}$. "Elegant" is a bit opinion-based. Do have more context or motivations, or did you just try with GAP?

Comment: GAP confirms that it is, indeed, $A_{11}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  If this gives something, then if we decompose these cycles into independent transpositions, you will get $(1, 2) (1, 3) ... (1, 5)$ and $(1, 6)(1 ,7)  ... (1, 11)$

Comment: @DietrichBurde What is GAP?

Comment: For information on GAP, see [here](https://www.gap-system.org/).

Comment: @Shaun thank you

Comment: As Derek Holt notes, the subgroup generated by your two cycles is transitive, hence primitive. Once you know this, you can use a [theorem of Jordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_theorem_(symmetric_group)#:~:text=In%20finite%20group%20theory%2C%20Jordan%27s,the%20alternating%20group%20An.) to see your subgroup is $A_{11}$.

Comment: @SteveD  That's right, but I was trying to make the point that the exercise was to decide whether the group is solvable, not to prove that it is equal to $A_{11}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=(1,2,3,4,5)$, $b=(1,6,7,8,9,10,11)$ and $G=\langle(a,b)\rangle$
To prove that $G=A_{11}$ we can proceed as follows.
We multiply permutations from left to right, e.g. $(1,2)(1,3)=(1,2,3)$.

1. $b^{-1}ab=(6,2,3,4,5)$.
   It follows that $(i,2,3,4,5)\in G$ for any $i\in\overline{6,11}$.
2. $(i,2,3,4,5)(j,5,4,3,2)=(i,j,5)$, $i,j\in\overline{6,11}$.
   It follows that $(i,j,k)\in G$ for any $i,j\in\overline{6,11}$ and $k\in\overline{1,5}$.
3. Similarly, $(i,6,7,8,9,10,11)\in G$ for any $i\in\overline{1,5}$ and
4. $(i,j,k)\in G$ for any $i,j\in\overline{1,5}$ and $k\in\overline{6,11}$.

The remaining cycles of length $3$ are obtained from the ones mentioned in (2) and (4).
For example $(1,2,3)=(1,2,6)(3,7,6)(1,6,7)$

We see that the group $G$ contains all cycles of length $3$, so $G=A_{11}$.

I don't know how elegant this way is.

Comment: From where in point 2 did we get the cycle of the form $(j,5,4,3,2)$?

Comment: @Quark $(j,5,4,3,2)=(j,2,3,4,5)^{-1}$.

Comment: why do we conclude in point 2 and 4 that all $(i, j, k)$ belong to our subgroup?

Comment: @Quark: For any three different symbols $i,j,k\in\overline{1,11}$ there are only four possibilities:

\begin{align*}
1)\ & i,j\in\overline{1,5}, k\in\overline{6,11},\\
2)\ & i,j\in\overline{6,11}, k\in\overline{1,5},\\
3)\ & i,j,k\in\overline{1,5},\\
4)\ & i,j,k\in\overline{6,11}.
\end{align*}
The first two possibilities are realized in items 2 and 4 of my answer, the third possibility is the example for (1,2,3). Consider the fourth possibility on your own.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was to decide whether the group is solvable. It is clearly transitive hence primitive, since $11$ is prime. If it was solvable then a minimal normal subgroup would be transitive and abelian, and hence of order $11$. But the normalizer of a subgroup of order $p$ in $S_p$ is easily seen to be a Frobenius group of order $p(p-1)$. In particular, it does not include $5$- and $7$-cycles when $p=11$, so we have a contradiction, and the group is not solvable.